# Trying to remove user from all groups in an Active Directory using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to use a PowerShell script to accept input from the user based on what user they want removed from all groups. Is my syntax wrong? Here's what I have so far.

```
$User1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the username of the employee you wish to change'

Get-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity CISCOVPN, FS-001
```

Where CISCOVPN and FS-001 are two of the groups I want `$User1` removed from. Is there a way to just say remove from all groups?

Comment: Have you run `Get-Help Remove-ADGroupMember -Full` yet?

Comment: Try to use Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership and Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership, these cmdlets should do the trick (these are cmdlets to view or remove groups for a specific user, although they can bug out in some rare cases)

Comment: As far as I know, you must have at least one group, which would be set to primary.  Which means, use Powershell to set the primary group you want and then Ansgar Wiechers script below will remove the other groups.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pipe the groups into `Remove-ADGroupMember` in a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
  $_.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: I don't think that'll work, since within your `ForEach` loop you pipe `$_.MemberOf` into `Remove-ADGroupMember`, at which point `$_` is a string representing the current group's DN, so `-Members $_.DistinguishedName` is not valid. Try `ForEach($User in (Get-ADUser $User1 -Prop MemberOf)){` and replace all instances of `$_` with `$User`.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician If you actually test it (like I did) you'll see that it does work. It may seem surprising at first, but `$_` is evaluated at parse time unless it's put in a nested context (simply speaking: a scriptblock). Basically, in a pipeline `foo $_ | bar $_` both `$_` refer to the same object while in a pipeline `foo $_ | bar { $_ }` the second `$_` refers to the output objects of the first command.

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user| foreach {Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -Members $user - 
Confirm:$false}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.