# Powershell: remove a list of users from an OU

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, data-cleaning

I am currently doing some AD cleaning and have a list of about 5000 users that need to be removed from two OU's. Each OU contains 150+ groups that a user could be a member of one or many.

I have two CSV's that I have generated:

```
List-of-users.csv
list-of-groups.csv
```

What I am trying:

```
$Us = import-csv List-of-users.csv

$Gs = import-csv list-of-groups.csv

ForEach($U in $US) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $U -MemberOf $Gs
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have both lists compare themselves against each user so no user will be in any group.

Whenever I run it `-WhatIf` shows that it is performing "Set" on the groups, but no changes will be made.

Comment: `-identity` takes a group name. `-members` takes a user array.

Comment: `OU` (Organizational Unit) is something else than a AD Group. [Understand the Difference Between AD OUs and Groups](https://www.itprotoday.com/security/access-denied-understand-difference-between-ad-ous-and-groups)

Comment: can you provide a sample scenario to expand on what you are trying to do

Comment: A scenario being on a weekly basis I will audit our terminated OU. In that OU several users have not been correctly terminated and their accounts will still be included in distribution lists. Given the large number of users and large number of lists I want to remove a lot of people from a lit if groups.

Comment: whats the harm in removing the user from all its group memberships? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144890/1390548

Comment: There honestly wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, I am sure you can remove the list of all users but i am not sure what happens if the user is not already part of the group. But this should work out,

```
$Us = import-csv List-of-users.csv
$Gs = import-csv list-of-groups.csv

ForEach($group in $Gs) {
    ForEach($user in $Us) {
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```